# Passing local variable as const reference in multithreaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management

I have thread which takes some of the local data for every job it spawns. I wanted to check if I can pass by reference of a "local variable" to a job (a functor)

For example,

```
ThreadPool tp;

void func(){

Employee emp;
tp.enqueueJob(bind(&foo,emp));

}


void foo(const Employee &emp){
//Access emp when the job is executed.
}
```

So, the question is, as per standard will I be guaranteed to have access to `Employee` record when the job is executed from `foo` after the control is out of `func`?

I know it is unsafe to assume we have access to local variables once we are out of the block, but just wanted to check because some of the compilers do allow returning a local variable as const reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bind(&foo,emp)
```

That takes a copy of `emp` and calls the function with that as the argument.

If that's what you want, then all is good. If you want the function to act on `emp` itself, then you'll need to:

- bind to a reference, `bind(&foo, std::ref(emp))`
- make sure the object lasts until the function finishes with it
- be careful to synchronise access between threads

Comment: Got it. Quick question, so you mean bind takes emp as value and passes to foo as const reference? (and use std::ref to make sure bind takes the ref too?)

Comment: @theAlias: That's right. `bind` produces an object containing copies of its arguments, which are used as arguments to the function; `ref` gives a "reference wrapper" type which acts like a reference to its argument.